# Standard implementation of RANK

Tags: ranking

I want to implement a functions which can distribute a certain number of rank-classes uniformly on a given sample of integers. For example for
[1,3,20,30,50,60] and 3 classes it would assign the numbers

- 1 -> 1
- 3 -> 1
- 20 -> 2
- 30 -> 2
- 50 -> 3
- 60 -> 3

Do you know of a standard implementation for this method? I'd like to implement it without additional libraries.
Ideally it should resemble the behaviour of SAS "RANK", but any accepted implementation will do.

I've made an attempt, however there are many special cases to consider (more classes than sample data, many equal sample data integers, ...). I'm not sure how to solve all anomalous cases sensibly in one implementation.

EDIT:
The comments pointed out that I actually want to "bin the data into quantiles". The input is some list of orderable numbers with possible duplicates. I want to assign bin classes 1 to [maxbin] uniformly. I will implement it in Python, but any advise in pseudocode or algorithm or rules is fine. My main concern are anomalous case where it isn't clear how to equal distribute all bins.

Here is my attempt in Python (which fails if there are more classes than sample data):

```
import bisect
import math

class QuantileClass:
    def __init__(self, classes, data, fallback=None):
        if not data:
            self.cutoffs=[]
            return

        self.bisect=bisect.bisect_left
        self.fallback=fallback

        s=sorted(data)
        num=len(s)
        cutoff_ranks=[math.ceil((num+1)/classes*c)-1 for c in range(1, classes)]
        self.cutoffs=[s[i-1] for i in cutoff_ranks]

    def __call__(self, value):
        if self.cutoffs:
            return self.bisect(self.cutoffs, value)
        else:
            return self.fallback
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do.  The question refers to "ranking" but the example instead appears to [bin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binning) data by [quantiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile).  Could you be more explicit about what kinds of inputs you have and what output you need?  Also, what software platform should the solution be in?  SAS?  Python?  Anything?

Comment: I'm sorry if the terminology is incorrect. I'll edit the post. I used "rank" since that's what the SAS command is. I will write it in Python, but just if someone knows the algorithm in any language/pseudocode, then I can implement it.